# Interchanging the limits (two-dimensional).

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f(x,y)$ be a function on the interior of an open region $M\subset\mathbb R\times\mathbb R$ that is continuously differentiable in $x$ and $y$.

Let $(x_0,y_1), (x_0,y_2)\in M$ be simple zeroes of $f$, that is $f(x_0,y_1)=0$ and $f(x_0,y_2)=0$.

QUESTION (for arguments and/or easily accessible literature):

Under what conditions on $f$ can we interchange the limits 
\begin{equation*}
\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x,y_1+h)}{f(x,y_2\pm h)}=
\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}\frac{f(x,y_1+h)}{f(x,y_2\pm h)}  
\end{equation*}
?

EDIT (changes):

A very simple example for $f(x,y)$ is $a(x-x_0)+b(y-y_1)(y-y_2)$, where the denominator uses "$-h$". For a discussion of the problem maybe it's useful to use Taylor series?

The zeroes should be simple, which means that the zeroes of $f$ are not zeroes of any derivative of $f$.

EXAMPLE: 
$$f(x,y):=g(x,y)(x-x_0)+h(x,y)(y-y_1)(y-y_2)$$ 
We get
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_0,y_1) \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x_0,y_2)\mp \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_0,y_2) \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x_0,y_1)=0$$

2th EDIT, I found the assigned theme:

Algebraic curves in the plane, Singular points of a curve

Comment: I fixed spelling and phrasing, but I don't know what "have to be used $-h$" (which is grammatically incorrect) means, so do see if what I changed it to is what you intended. I think your condition of continuously differentiable is not enough, because $f(x,y)$ could wildly oscillate about $0$ for $x \ne x_0$ and $y \to y_2$, making the inner limit on the left not exist while allowing the limit on the right to exist.

Comment: Thanks for your comment ! I know now, that I have to study Singular points of a curve.